Is it possible to perform fuzzy matching for labels, relationships, or properties in a Cypher query in Memgraph?
I need to implement fuzzy matching in my Cypher queries. I want to account for slight variations or errors in user input. For example, if a user inputs "apartment" instead of "apartments" or makes a typo like "apprtment," I still want the query to match the closest value. How to do that?

This can be achieved with the node similarity procedure.
